# Linq to XML pulling back an attribute that exists on a different level

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to write a Linq to XML query that pulls back keyword and includes an attribute (mediatype)

Consider the following XML data...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<media>
    <photos>        
        <photo mediatype="photo" photographer="Jag_cz" description="Colored splashes in abstract shape, isolated on white background" id="16" name="50623755_F.jpg" folder="HR Headset">
            <keywords>
                <keyword>fish</keyword>
                <keyword>abstract</keyword>         
            </keywords>
        </photo>
    </photos>
    <videos>
        <video mediatype="video" description="Bear by a stream" folder="streamfolder" name="stream.mp4">
            <keywords>
                <keyword>stream</keyword>
                <keyword>river</keyword>
                <keyword>water</keyword>
            </keywords>
        </video>
        <video mediatype="video" description="Stream with a bear" folder="bearfolder" name="bear.mp4">
            <keywords>
                <keyword>salmon</keyword>
                <keyword>fish</keyword>
            </keywords>
        </video>
    </videos>
</media>
```

There are photo elements and video elements. Each element has a mediattype attribute.

I want pull back a query of each keyword with it's media type.

Something like this..

```
mediatype   keyword
---------   -------              
photo       fish
photo       abstract
video       stream
video       river
video       water
video       salmon
video       fish
```

I have been able to pull back the keywords with the following code...

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String strPath = @"C:\videodata\media.xml";

        XElement xEle = XElement.Load(strPath);

        var keywordquery = from k in xEle.Descendants("keyword")
                           select new
                               {
                                   keyword = (string)k.Value
                               };

        foreach (var k in keywordquery)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(k.keyword);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press <enter> to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

However, I'm stuck on pulling back the mediatype attribute. This attribute exists on a different level than keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var query=  xEle.Descendants().Where(e=>e.Name=="photo" || e.Name=="video")
                              .SelectMany(e=>e.Descendants("keyword")
                                              .Select(x=>new {mediatype=e.Name,
                                                              keyword=x.Value
                                                             }));
```

In summary, you select first all the nodes with name  `photo` and `video`, and then per each of these elements you need to get the keywords inside.Using the `SelectMany` extension method you flatten the result to finally get just one collection

Comment: This is the answer and it just shows me that I still have a lot to learn about Linq to Xml.  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome @codingguy3000, there are multiples ways to do it using linq, it is really powerful once you know how to use it, i definitely recommends you learn more about it, happy codding ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this as well:

```
var keywordquery = from k in xEle.Descendants("keyword")
                   select new
                   {
                       keyword = (string)k.Value,
                       mediatype = (string)k.Parent.Parent.Attribute("mediatype")
                   };
```

As long as you know that the `video` element with the `mediatype` will always be the grandparent element.  If not, you should probably use something like `Ancestors()` to find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have stable structure of your XML file you can use simple select:

```
  var keywordquery = xEle.Descendants("keyword")
    .Select(x => new { MediaType = x.Parent?.Parent.Attribute("mediatype").Value, KeyWords = x.Value});

  foreach (var k in keywordquery)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"{k.MediaType} | {k.KeyWords}");
  }

  Console.WriteLine("Press <enter> to continue");
  Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: But solution with `SelectMany` are really elegant.